# haskell: read does not parse floating point numbers without explicit type

Tags: haskell

Consider the following function

```
add1 :: Num a => a -> a
add1 x = x + 1
```

and the following applications

```
*Main> add1 2
3
*Main> add1 2.2
3.2
*Main> add1 (read "1")
2
add1 (read "1.5"::Float)
2.5
*Main> add1 (read "1.5")
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Why does the last invication of `add1` fail for floating point numbers, while it works for integers? Why do I have to specify a type in that case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GHCi gives it type

```
> :t add1 (read "1.5")
add1 (read "1.5") :: (Read a, Num a) => a
```

So, its still polymorphic. However, when evaluated in GHCi, it implicitly `print`ed, so GHCi must pick some concrete type for `a`. GHCi uses [the defaulting rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules), and statically chooses `a = Integer`. Note that this choice is done statically (during type checking, roughly), and only depends on types (e.g. `String`), not actual values (e.g. `"1.5"`). `Integer` is both a `Read` and a `Num`, so all static checks pass.

More in detail, GHCi tries types `()`, `Integer`, `Double` -- in that order, unless there is a `default` declaration saying otherwise.

Then, at run-time the code behaves as

```
> add1 (read "1.5") :: Integer
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

since the string can not be parsed. By comparison, this would be fine:

```
> add1 (read "1.5") :: Float
2.5
```

Comment: I think a key point is that the type is inferred/chosen statically, and does not depend on the string. Also, I believe this defaulting rule is actually standard.

Comment: @dfeuer The standard defaulting rule (without GHCi's `ExtendedDefaultRules` extension) leaves out `()`, and works in fewer circumstances.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, I know, but I believe it works in this one.